# Spring and tomcat or Spring and Glassfish

Tags: spring, tomcat, glassfish

To run Spring application, should I use Tomcat ( Servlet engine) or an application server like Glassfish? Thanks a lot

Comment: Or [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/)?

Comment: Yes, I meant an application server is mondatory for Spring application to run, or a servlet engine can do the Job?

Comment: It really depends on if you need full Java EE support. There are plenty of applications out there running very nicely on _just_ a servlet engine. If you could add some more detail to the question about what you want to do, it might get some better answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to run a Spring application as a stand-alone Java application without any form of J2EE container at all. Assuming the application is some form of web based application then (unless you like re-inventing wheels) you will need a container and you have a choice of three categories:

1. Servlet container (usually includes JSP & EL support). e.g. Apache Tomcat
2. J2EE Web Profile container. e.g. Apache TomEE
3. Full J2EE container. e.g. Apache Geronimo

The options are listed in order of increasing functionality. Generally, I'd recommend pickign the class of container with the minimum functionality you need now and are likely to need in the short to medium term. I've listed the Apache containers as examples but there are plenty of others, both open and closed source.

The majority of Spring based applications that I see (I'm employed by SpringSource) run on category 1 containers (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.) but there are still plenty running on the other categories as well (for a variety of reasons).